# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool Science Fiction or Fantasy events/conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/7946).

Comment: For reference, 2015 ads are [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5326/3567).

Answer (score 16):

[image: No, I don't know what planet this is on either.]

Comment: Advertises [worldbuilding.se], unsuprisingly. We just graduated and got a new design, so this is designed to fit nicely with that.

Comment: Wow, cool design!

Comment: @randal'thor The ad or the site? Or both?

Comment: The new site design (I went and found it on WB meta). The ad is a bit too cityscape-ish for my taste; I prefer the more old-fashioned kind of fantasy :-)

Comment: I like this ad quite a bit but the "Welcome to Oskeron" seems out of place. IMO it would look much better without that.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Movies & TV Stack Exchange]

Comment: Adapted from [last year's ad](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5328/23386).

Answer (score 14):

[image: Join us and discover your great-great-great-grandfather's SciFi & Fantasy!]

Comment: +1 OMG I just laughed out loud (lol'd so hard) when I see this ad on the sidebar. Well done!

Answer (score 12):

[image: There's a Blog?]

Comment: I'd say "we have a blog?"

Answer (score 11):

[image: Support the Literature proposal for non-SFF books!]

Comment: This proposal is "lit". Ok thanks bye.

Comment: Emphasis *bye*.....

Answer (score 11):

[image: Get Crafty!]

Comment: There you go, I just put this to a score of 6.

Comment: I feel like this is channeling me. I love it regardless. You should link to this in our ac meta I would think http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/258/lets-advertise-the-community-on-some-related-sites

Answer (score 10):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/scifi.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: Copied from last year; the size should not be a problem.

Comment: My only issue with this ad is it doesn't look very specifically SFFy (unless there's a reference I'm missing, which is quite possible).

Comment: @Randal'Thor There's an Invisible Time-travelling Robot in there somewhere, but you need magic vision to see it! Or at least that's what the oracles told me.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: In previous years there has been a competition to see which site can downvote their twitter ads the most. Let's join in!

Comment: But who upvoted it?

Comment: @curiousdannii that started as users did not like the questions that were tweeted. I like the ones that get tweeted,  so I've upvoted.

Comment: Did something change? This is no longer looking [quite right](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae07r.png)

Comment: This doesn't show any image for me

Comment: @curiousdannii: This is now appearing in the sidebar as an ad.  I think we may have lost that competition.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Do you know what Napoleon rode in Battle? Join History.SE]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Need more Potter? Visit J.K. Rowling’s Pottermore.com for fresh Potter facts and fun! Updated regularly.]

Comment: Since Pottermore has gotten an overhaul, I thought it was time our Pottermore Community Promotion Ad got one, too, reflecting the new layout of the site. This version builds on the [previous version](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6394/43655), put together by Slytherincess, SQB, and Richard; I’ve kept SQB’s brilliant motto and redone the graphics myself.

Answer (score -8):

[image: Support Paranormal proposal]